# What do those CSS properties mean while centering a form element?

Tags: html, css, width, margin, center

While searching for how to center a `form` element in `CSS`, I found that I have to set `margin` to `auto` and then set a `width` property. But, what does `width` represent here?

When I for example set the `width` to `350px` I get the form to the center, while when setting it to `5px` for example, I don't get it centered.

Can you kindly explain what `width` represents here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

width is the width of the element itself when it is displayed, the width is required to be set so that the browser will be able to automatically calculate the margins around the element so that it will appear centered.  As for why a value of 5px doesn't center the element and 350px does I'm not sure, I've never encountered that problem, perhaps it's just that the form can't be re-sized that small so it is automatically changed by the browser to a width of auto.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, the `width` here doesn't change the width of the element. I'm dealing here with a `form` element. For example,  I have set its `width` in the `CSS` part of the document as follows: `form { width: 200px;}`. Now, I have put a `<div id="formsection">` around `<form>`, and in the `CSS` part I made the following: `#formsection{margin: auto; width: 350px}`. In the later part I found that `width` has different effect than in the first one. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple test to show what's happening:

**HTML**

```
/* This form will be 200px and centered within its parent element */
<form></form>

/* #formsection is 300px and not centered.  The form it contains will be 
   200px and centered withint #formsection */
<div id="formsection">
    <form></form>
</div
```

**CSS**

```
/* All forms will be 200px and centered in their parent container */
form {
  width: 200px;        
  margin: 0 auto;      
  border: 1px solid red;   
}

/* #formsection is 300px in width and not centered */
#formsection {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#formsection form {
  border: 1px solid green;   
}
```

You can see a [demo of it here](http://jsfiddle.net/guYuH/).

You had mentioned that `width` isn't changing the element width.  This is possible if your `<form>` has a child element that is wider than the width you set on it (i.e. your `5px` case).  To test, add a `border` or `background-color` to your child elements and check if any are overflowing the form.

Another, faster, alternative is to use the [Web Developer addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) for Firefox.  Once it's installed, `CTRL+SHIFT+Y` will show the style information of any element you hover over.